# Workaround for "Visual Studio Web Request handler could not be found" when using github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017, protocol-handler

When I choose "Open in Visual Studio" on github, I get the following error:

> "Visual Studio Web Request handler could not be found"

I believe this is due to the git-client protocol handler not being registered properly.

There's a closed bug for VS2015 listed here but no workaround: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/140

I've tried to repair Visual Studio 2017 but that didn't fix it. 
Is there a workaround, perhaps by editing HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\git-client entries?

Comment: You should really spend 3 secs to mark the comment as an answer

Comment: @DonBox I have no idea if it's the right answer, since it was answered 3 months after my issue.

Comment: That's really is the answer :)

Answer (score 27):

The solution is easy: just reassign the default handler for the git-client protocol. 
To do that, press the Windows-Key, enter "default apps" and select the settings page. Go down, select "Choose default apps by protocol" and look for "git-client". Click and select the Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handler Selector for VS2017.

[image]

When you click the "Open in Visual Studio" - button in Github, Visual Studio 2017 should open and you can clone the repo in Team Explorer.

Comment: Also useful when you want to change the VS version it opens with :)

Comment: For anyone who has VS 2017 and 2019 preview, the icons look very much the same. If one doesnt work, just try the other one.